# How can I make a two-finger tap on touch pad take me to my desktop?

Tags: mouse, ubuntu-touch, touchpad, multi-touch, synaptics

I recently switched to Ubuntu and have been customizing all my settings as much as possible. Now, I'm not sure how I did it (since it was a while back ago) but in Windows 7 I found a way to make my desktop show when I two finger tapped the touch pad. It would also bring me back

So essentially, I would tap the touch pad with two finger and my desktop would show, when I tapped it again it would take me back to the window I was on previously.

Does anyone know how I could configure this?

Edit: I am using Ubuntu 14.04 on an Acer Aspire Timeline X. I can provide more details on my hardware if needed.

Answer (score 0):

In linux, in general, two-finger tap is emulating a right-mouse-button click in the current mouse position. Do you not want the right mouse button emulation?
Anyway, you can easily configure what you asked if using KDE, with its internal system of global hotkeys. Default Ubuntu desktop, Unity, does not allow you to configure a lot.

Comment: Yeah, I don't really care for the right mouse button emulation. I'd rather have the desktop shortcut than the right click emulation. Is KDE already on Ubuntu or should I download and install it?

Comment: Actually, I just understand that you have touhpad and mouse, and want to keep right-click on mouse, right? Then you will need `touchegg` utility. Search about it. It may be unable to see two-finger actions if you have scrolling configured on them in GUI.